# Add an anchor element to first className in a list

Tags: jquery, class, anchor

I have a long list of names, and I want to add an anchor to the first element in a given class.

```
<ul id="the_names">
    <li class="names letter-A">Ames, Aldrich</li>
    <li class="names letter-A">Andrews, Richard</li>
    <li class="names letter-B">Barber, Deborah</li>
    <li class="names letter-B">Brown, Bobby</li>
    <li class="names letter-C">Clark, Richard</li>
    <li class="names letter-C">Coates, Charles</li>
    <li class="names letter-D">Day, Doris</li>
    <li class="names letter-D">Dole, Elizabeth</li>
</ul>
```

I've tried several methods using jQuery to get all the class names used by the li's, but all are coming up short, usually just returning `names letter-A`.

What I want to end up with is an anchor tag at the FIRST occurrence of the class `letter-A`, same at letter-B, letter-C, etc.:

```
<ul id="the_names">
    <li class="names letter-A"><a name="letter-A">Ames, Aldrich</a></li>
    <li class="names letter-A">Andrews, Richard</li>
    <li class="names letter-B"><a name="letter-A">Barber, Deborah</a></li>
    <li class="names letter-B">Brown, Bobby</li>
    <li class="names letter-C"><a name="letter-A">Clark, Richard</a></li>
    <li class="names letter-C">Coates, Charles</li>
    <li class="names letter-D"><a name="letter-A">Day, Doris</a></li>
    <li class="names letter-D">Dole, Elizabeth</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: why do you want the same class name? You can access it as `$('names.letter-A:first-child a')`

Comment: The list is over a thousand names, read in to the page dynamically. I'm trying to create a jump menu to the first name in an alphabetical group.

Comment: Sorry, when copying my list I failed to change the names. The name should match the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lq3uf/

jQuery

```
//Inititalize an array to hold the classes
var importantClasses = [];

//Enumerate the array with the classes
$("#the_names li.names").each(function () {
    var myClass = $(this).attr("class").split(" ")[1];
    if (importantClasses.indexOf(myClass) === -1) {
        importantClasses.push(myClass)
    }
})

$.each(importantClasses, function (index, value) {
    var item = $("." + value).eq(0)
    var html = item.html();
    item.html("<a name='" + value + "'>" + html + "</a>")
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below sample code.

```
var object = $('.names.letter-A').first();
var text = object.html();
object.html($("<a></a>")
          .attr('href', '#')
          .attr('name', object.attr('class').split(" ").pop())
          .text(text));
```

Answer (score 0):

once you have the results of a jQuery selector you can just use `get()` (http://api.jquery.com/get/) to get the element you need.

Alternatively, if you do not need to access the underlying DOM element that `get()` gives you, you can use `first()` (http://api.jquery.com/first/).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, given the following HTML:

```
<ol id="navigation"></ol>

<ul id="the_names">
    <li class="names letter-A">Ames, Aldrich</li>
    <li class="names letter-A">Andrews, Richard</li>
    <li class="names letter-B">Barber, Deborah</li>
    <li class="names letter-B">Brown, Bobby</li>
    <li class="names letter-C">Clark, Richard</li>
    <li class="names letter-C">Coates, Charles</li>
    <li class="names letter-D">Day, Doris</li>
    <li class="names letter-D">Dole, Elizabeth</li>
</ul>
```

The following jQuery:

```
var navigation = $('#navigation'),
    nav, link;

// gets all the `li` elements that contain the string 'letter-' in their class attribute:    
$('li[class*="letter-"]').filter(function(){
    /* filters those elements, keeping only those elements that meet the following criteria:

       this.previousElementSibling === null
       will match only the first element of the list, by definition
       also the first instance of the first letter.

       this.previousElementSibling.className !== this.className
       if the className of this element is different from the className
       of the previous element, we assume a different letter. This does
       assume that the class-names will be arranged in identical order.
    */
    return this.previousElementSibling === null || this.previousElementSibling.className !== this.className;
}).each(function(){
    var firstLetter = $(this).text()[0].toUpperCase();

    // setting the id, instead of using a named-anchor        
    this.id = 'first-' + firstLetter;

    // creating an `li` element, appending to the '#navigation' element
    nav = $('<li />').appendTo(navigation);
    /* creating an 'a' element, setting the href to target the
       newly-created 'id', and setting the text to the firstLetter variable */
    link = $('<a />', {'href' : '#first-' + firstLetter, 'text' : firstLetter}).appendTo(nav);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/F3k3G/1/).

References:

- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [attribute-contains selector (`[attribute*=value]`)](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).